# How to detect if a boost::function is pure virtual?

Tags: c++, boost, pure-virtual, boost-function

I've got a task pool using threads which is trying to call a boost::function that happens to be purely virtual, without an implementation.

Is there anything like this?

```
void doStuff(boost::function<void()> foo) 
{
    if (!foo.pure_virtual) 
    {
        foo();
    }
}
```

**Note:**  This isn't the same as `foo.empty` or `if (foo) { }`.  The `.empty` API doesn't seem to detect the pure virtual-ness of the method.

Comment: Could you provide a concrete example of "boost::function that happens to be purely virtual"?

Comment: How did you manage to instantiate a class containing a pure virtual function? Sounds like you're calling `doStuff()` from somewhere you shouldn't be (for instance, from within a constructor or destructor of a class in the inheritance hierarchy).

Comment: A pure virtual points to null no? Another thing is you have to bind the function to an object, and that should not be possible with a pure virtual

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You cannot detect it, and you shouldn't have it in there in the first place!

Comment: * Agreed that it shouldn't be happening in the first place.  Thanks for the example.

Comment: "// This will not do virtual dispatch" --- this statement is false. Have you tried to run your code?

Comment: @bitcycle: this might be OK with you but the answer is built on a wrong assumption and is factually incorrect. `boost::bind(&Foo::f, &foo)(); ` **will** do virtual dispatch in this case.

Comment: Woa, I was sure it wouldn't dispatch virtually but you guys are correct! I removed the wrong bits. Would have deleted the answer, but can't since it's accepted.